# Are there conditions that valgrind will not report existing leaks/erros

Tags: c++, c, debugging, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm checking out valgrind for the first time and I like the current results, however I'm curious to whether valgrind will always return memory leaks that it has encountered or if some may get away from it, specificity depending on how the program is shut down. For example, if a program is killed using 'killall -9 program'.

Here's the result of my current program, stopped by using 'end process' in the Ubuntu System Monitor

```
==10182== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10182==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10182==   total heap usage: 8,747,225 allocs, 8,747,225 frees, 1,352,535,387 bytes allocated
==10182== 
==10182== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==10182== 
==10182== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Does this result confirm that there was literally zero leaks or context errors?

Comment: I'd pay less attention to "in use at exit" and more to the fact that the number of allocs and frees match.  That means you didn't have any memory that leaked until the entire heap/pool was released -- everything was correctly and individually freed.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Can you expand on that in an answer?

Comment: I don't know what signal System Monitor sends.  Use (at command prompt) either `kill -TERM pid` or `kill -KILL pid`.  The first should trigger your termination logic, which valgrind will track.  In the second case your process and the valgrind library it hosts will just be gone -- no chance to report leaks.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/wiki/ComparisonOfMemoryTools), Vallgrind can't detect stack out of bounds, global out of bounds and use after return.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still not clear. For example I had failed to initialize a property and was receiving a context error when it's objects destructor was being called. This didn’t happen when I used 'killall', but did the first time I used 'end process'. This would have been the last object to destroy. Am I wrong to assume that valgrind would have still been able to report memory issues at this point?

Comment: Ah ok I probably misunderstood your question.